# Managing sessions between different servers

Tags: php, asp.net

How are session of same user maintained when a load balancer is used with different web servers at backend . In other words lets suppose there is a load balancer to distribute load between different servers and a user is directed to one server where its session is stored and then next time the same user is directed to second server. How does servers know if it is same user ? how to maintain it that it was the same user on both servers

Comment: Is this for an ASP.NET application or php?

Comment: general question and i just require a general answer like how is it generally done , an interview question you can say

Answer (score 0):

I made it, by changing the session storage form files, to another system which can handle tcp connections (in my case memcache, but you can even use mysql as it)

memcache solution: 
for memcache extension

```
session.save_handler = memcache 
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:11211"
```

for memcacheD

```
session.save_handler = memcached 
session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```

, but of course, you should change localhost to your dns/ip

check it in manual [Sessions support](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your solution please

Answer (score 0):

Your load balancer can be configured to direct the same user/client to the same server.  The only time this becomes "tricky" is when jumping between SSL and unsecured traffic, but this can still be configured on your load balancer.

If, for whatever reason, you are unable to do this, you may store/retrieve the session state in a SQL server.  Please see [this article for direction.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Answer (score 0):

Use a database for session storage.
(Beware of SQL injection, since the cookie holding PHPSESSID comes from the client.)

Start here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php